# How to use css/html to hide image with src like *-1.jpg or *-1.gif?

Tags: html, css, image, css-selectors, hide

I want to hide some images in tag img src, they have name look like `*-1.jpg`, `*-2.jpg` or `*-1.gif`, how can I do it? I found some answer as below, but I am not sure how to use them for my question...

```css
img[src='']{
    display: none;
}
img[src='Error.src']{
    display: none;
}
```

I hope to hide img src, but show a href, is this possible?

```
<a href="http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/mikezang/clonebrick/stardiamond/80029.jpg" title="星钻／军事／CV-12 侦察吉普车&lt;br /&gt;Star Diamond／Military／CV-12 Reconnaissance Vehicle">
<img src="http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/mikezang/clonebrick/stardiamond/80029.jpg" height="64" />
```

Comment: You want to hide all whose source is like *-1 irrespective of the type (that is gif or jpg) or only a few types? Also, do you want to hid only `*-1.*` or `*-[number].*`?

Comment: Are you dynamically hiding, or just hiding on load?  For dynamically, you need javascript.

Comment: I need to hide all ¥*-[number].¥* on load.

Comment: As far as I know, CSS does not have a regex type selector. So you'll either have to manually write as many selectors as in the number range (say 1-9  or 1-99 whatever) or use scripting.

Comment: Please could you edit the question as I assume it is supposed to say *jpg* and not *jog* in the first line. Also, the format you mention in the comment `¥*-[number].¥` does not match a) the format in the question text or b) the format in the example source. The question is inconsistent and difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$=` [attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) to match the end of the `src` attribute.

> #### `[att$=val]`
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value ends with the suffix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

Your question is a bit vague on exactly what you want to hide, but based on what you've provided, I think the simplest solution is to have three separate selectors to match each case:

```css
img[src$="-1.jpg"], img[src$="-2.jog"], img[src$="-1.gif"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I met new problem, please check my question.

Answer (score 0):

CSS has the ability to target HTML elements based on any one of their **[attributes](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)**. You probably already know about classes and IDs. **[more info](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)**